# Security concern on login system

Tags: reactjs, security, authentication, web

I am building a web app like Instagram by using redux and react. The index page contains the login system and main page depends on whether users have logged in or not.

In my home page, I use user info and token status to decide whether go home page or login page. If I did not login and just create the token in localStorage, then I still can go to the home page. But what issue I am facing is that if I don't use token to determine which page user should see because even user login, if user presses reload, then they can see the login page at few second and turn to home page (due to the duration of fetching)

Should I use token to determine the which page user should see or any suggestions? Thank you!

[image]

**auth Reducer**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { getAuthToken, setAuthToken } from "../../utlis";
import { registerAPI, loginAPI, getMeAPI } from "../../services/authAPI";

export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: {
    user: null,
    alertMsg: null,
    isLoadingUser: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    setUsers: (state, action) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
    setAlertMsg: (state, action) => {
      state.alertMsg = action.payload;
    },
    setIsLoadingUser: (state, action) => {
      state.isLoadingUser = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setUsers, setAlertMsg, setIsLoadingUser } = authSlice.actions;

export const getCurrentUser = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(setIsLoadingUser(true));
  if (getAuthToken()) {
    return getMeAPI().then((res) => {
      dispatch(setIsLoadingUser(false));
      if (res.message !== "Successfully get the user") {
        setAuthToken(null);
        return;
      }
      dispatch(setUsers(res));
      return res;
    });
  }
  dispatch(setIsLoadingUser(false));
};

export const login = (email, password) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(setIsLoadingUser(true));
  return loginAPI(email, password).then((res) => {
    if (res.message !== "Successfully login") {
      dispatch(setAlertMsg(res.message));
      return;
    }
    setAuthToken(res.token);
    return dispatch(getCurrentUser());
  });
};
```

**Home page**

```
const classes = useStyles();
  const user = useSelector(selectUser);
  console.log(user);
  const token = getAuthToken();

  return user || token ? (
    <>
      <Container maxWidth="lg" className={classes.root}>
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>Posts You've Liked</Paper>
        <Grid container direction="row" justify="center">
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <GridList />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          size="large"
          className={classes.button}
          startIcon={<ArrowDropDownCircleRoundedIcon />}
        >
          Read More
        </Button>
        {/* press read more and call the content api */}
        <Grid container spacing={1} direction="row" justify="center">
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={3}>
            <SimpleCardComponent />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={3}>
            <SimpleCardComponent />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={3}>
            <SimpleCardComponent />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={3}>
            <SimpleCardComponent />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </>
  ) : (
    <SignInPage />
  );
```

Comment: you can make a wrapper component which tries to get and verify the token. If everything is fine it renders its child else sends user to login. Then you can simply use this wrapper to protect any of your routes. You can google and get plenty of examples.

Comment: Could you explain more about the method you suggest?

Comment: try searching `protect routes react` on google and you should get examples that will help you out. I can't provide external link here